# I want to add google fonts in function file of theme

Tags: wordpress, google-font-api

I want to add fonts to my theme. So i have used the bellow code for this.

```
function load_fonts() {
            wp_register_style('et-googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300');
            wp_register_style('et-googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts');
        }
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

So i have to use many fonts like Helvetica, Palatino and Trebuchet in the function. But i dont know how to add those fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function theme_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts', "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts1', "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300" );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_assets' );
```

Also there must be `wp_head()` in your header file to make this work.!

Comment: I have to more fonts like Helvetica, Palatino and Trebuchet

Comment: You can do those yourself, we're not here to do all of your work for you. Hemnath is just showing you how to do it.

Comment: @Ranjit You can replicate this line into your function and change URL and Slug `wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts1', "NEXT_GOOGLE_FONT_URL" );` edited my answer.